# Why do we need to Inflate a layout and attachToRoot in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I was given this code:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wednesday, container, false)
    }
```

and I don't understand why we need to Inflate a layout and write attachToRoot value.
btw, why do we need a viewGroup?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean), https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 2):

A layout definition is just some XML data but to really show a layout it must be converted to a tree of objects. The inflater does that.

A container (`ViewGroup`) is necessary to control where (in a larger tree of view objects) the inflated subtree should be placed.

Answer (score 2):

consider this code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup fragment_container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, fragment_container, false);
}
```

The second parameter fragment_container is a container(framelayout) with id fragment_container that activity uses to add view of fragment in its layout.

No if we read source code of inflate method of LayoutInflater class, we get this( i removed unnecessary shit here to make you understand code better)

```
// The view that would be returned from this method.
View result = root;

// Temp is the root view that was found in the xml.                     
final View temp = createViewFromTag(root, name, attrs, false);
```

Firstly, it creates a temp view from the supplied root.

In case attachToRoot is false, it does this :

```
// Decide whether to return the root that was passed in or the
// top view found in xml.
   if (root == null || !attachToRoot) {
         result = temp;
     }
```

In case attachToRoot is false, it simply returns the root of the fragment's xml, i.e. the container parameter is just used to get layoutParams for fragment's root view (since it doesn't have a root, so it needs params from somewhere).

In case attachToRoot is true, it does this :

```
 // We are supposed to attach all the views we found (int temp)
 // to root. Do that now.
  if (root != null && attachToRoot) {
           root.addView(temp, params);
    }
```

It adds the temp view created above to the root view (i.e. container).

The main difference between the "third" parameter attachToRoot being true or false is this.

**true** : add the child view to parent RIGHT NOW

**false**: add the child view to parent NOT NOW. Add it later. `

**When is that later?**

That later is when you use for eg parent.addView(childView)

**A common misconception** is, if attachToRoot parameter is false then the child view will not be added to parent. **WRONG**
In both cases child view will be added to parentView. It is just the matter of **time**.

```
inflater.inflate(child,parent,false);
parent.addView(child);
```

**is equivalent to**

```
inflater.inflate(child,parent,true);
```

**NOTE !! NOTE !! NOTE !!**

You should never pass attachToRoot as true when you are not responsible for adding the child view to parent.

Eg When adding Fragment

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent,Bundle bundle)
  {
        super.onCreateView(inflater,parent,bundle);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment,parent,false);
       return v;
  }
```

now , if you pass third parameter as true you will get IllegalStateException because of the following piece of code.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .add(parent, childFragment)
  .commit();
```

Since you have already added the child fragment in onCreateView() by mistake. Calling add will tell you that child view is already added to parent , hence IllegalStateException. This Exception comes from the following piece of code which can be found while inspecting inflate method in LayoutInflater class

```
if (child.getParent() != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The specified child already has a parent. " +
                "You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.");
    }
```

Here you are not responsible for adding childView, FragmentManager is responsible. So always pass false in this case